# Mechanism for oxidative workup of ozonide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons, organic-oxidation, ozone

Oxidative workup of ozonide produces ketone (in case both the substituents of carbon are alkyl groups) or carboxylic acid (in case one of the substituents is hydrogen), depending on the alkene. I have tried for the following mechanism with hydrogen peroxide but unable to find the exact one.

[image]

Comment: Use blue electrons to break C-O (green) bond. Add peroxide to cation and protonate green oxygen. Now break both O-O bonds with loss of water. Hydrolyze the anhydride.

Comment: As RCO2H begins to form, it will catalyze the opening of the ozonide.

Comment: @user55119 Thanks, but I am unable to follow or see any pattern and seems like one has to mug up this mechanism. I thought that the first step should be the cleavage of weak peroxide bond of unstable ozonide.